# Looking for advice on how to implement Likes

Tags: architecture, database-design, django

I'm using Django and Django-Rest-Framework to build a simple photo sharing app/website and just now getting around to implementing a "Like" system. A couple of options I've thought about (surely there are more):

1. In my `Photo` model, add a Many-to-Many `like` field containing `users` that like the photo. My concern with this, although seemingly the most straightforward way, is that it might not scale very well.
2. Create a separate `PhotoLike` model. This seems like the right way to be able to scale, but I'm not sure exactly how to implement it. Maybe the joins would be costly?

Are there other ways? I've looked around a bit, but haven't really found many useful posts about this (specifically in Django, although other web frameworks would be helpful too at this point).

Comment: Why would this PhotoLike model be any different than a many-to-many relationship between Photo and Likes?  Why wouldn't this "scale well" in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

Both your solutions are pretty much the same, since with SQL databases you cant directly have a many-to-many relation, you have to have a table to join them. e.g. with a `photo_id`, `user_id` and maybe time, which is pretty much what your `PhotoLike` record would be anyway.

To display the like count just use a `SELECT COUNT` style query, rather than actually fetching all the `PhotoLike` (or `User`) records. And to ensure each user can only like a given photo once, you can add a unique constraint for both the `photo_id` and `user_id` columns (meaning the combination must be unique).

Just make sure you have indexes and I would leave it at that until you know it is a problem with data you actually have.

You can optimise it by adding a `like_count` to the `Photo`, and then to display the photos you dont need a second (or nested/join/etc.) query at all, but then you must also add some extra logic when adding or removing likes to ensure this stays in sync.

Comment: Would you also add comments as a ManyToMany field in the same way?

Comment: Well at the technical level more or less since a comment belongs to a user and a article/photo/whatever (so 2 foreign keys), but no unique constraint (unless you want to limit comments on something to one per user). But I wouldnt describe it that way, comments are more like their own little article with content etc., rather than a count with tracking linking a user and photo together.